# Service worker in Gin-Gonic

Tags: go, web-applications, go-gin

Did you know how to add a service worker in a go app ?

I serve the file like this: `r.StaticFile("/sw.js", "./front/sw.js")`

But I have this error in my console when I load the service worker:

> "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a
> ServiceWorker for scope ('https://example/') with script
> ('https://example/sw.js'): Operation has been aborted"

(I have replaced my domain by 'example')